# Why is [x|x<-[1..10]] method so slow in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Why is something like this runs extremely slow in Haskell?

```
test = [x|a<-[1..100],b<-[1..100],c<-[1..100],d<-[1..100],let x = a]

print $ length test
```

There are only about `10^8` numbers to run, it should be done in a blink of eye, but it seems like running forever and almost crashed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "why" question, but: compile with optimizations. I observe 25s in ghci; 20s when compiled with `-O0`; but only 0.3s when compiled with `-O2`.

Comment: Why the final answer is 10^8 not 100 as there is an assignment `let x = a`?

Comment: @Kamel `let x = a` is after all the binds, so `x` must be still replicated 10^8 times.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Then what does `let x = a` mean if it does not take effects on the final `test` result?

Comment: @Kamel It means that `x` is now bound to `a`. The thing is that because of the definition of `(>>=)` in lists, the value of `a` (hence `x`) depends on all the binds. For example and to really demonstrate the effect of how merely having a binding affects the result: `[5| _ <- [1..10]]` outputs `[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]`.

Comment: @MasterMastic Great example and info, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running this in ghci or in a compiled program? It makes a big difference.

If in ghci, then ghci will keep the computed value of `test` around in case you want to use it later. Normally this is a good idea, but not in this case where `test` is a huge value that would be cheap to recompute anyways. How huge? For starters it's a list of 10^8 elements, and (on a 64-bit system) a list costs 24 bytes per element, so that's 2.4G already. Then there is space usage of the values themselves. One might think the values are all taken from `[1..100]`, so they should be shared and use a negligible amount of space in total. But the values in the list are really of the form `x`, which could depend on `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, and `length` never examines the values in the list as it traverses it. So each element is going to be represented as a closure that refers to `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, which takes at least 8*(4+1) = 40 more bytes, bringing us to a total of 6.4G.

That's rather a lot, and the garbage collector has to do quite a lot of copying when you allocate 6.4G of data, all of it permanently live. That's what takes so long, not actually computing the list or its length.

If you compile the program

```
test = [x|a<-[1..100],b<-[1..100],c<-[1..100],d<-[1..100],let x = a]

main = print $ length test
```

then `test` does not have to be kept live as its length is being computed, as clearly it is never going to be used again. So now the GC has almost no work to do, and the program runs in a couple seconds (reasonable for ~10^8 list node allocations and computations on `Integer`).

Answer (score 4):

You're not just running a loop 10^8 times, you're creating a list with 10^8 elements. Since you're using `length`, Haskell has to actually evaluate the entire list to return its length. Each element in the list takes one word, which might be 32 bits or might be 64 bits. On the optimistic assumption that it's 32 bits (4 bytes), you've just allocated 400 MB (about 381.5 MiB) of memory. If it's 64 bits, then that's 800 MB (about 763 MiB) of memory you've just allocated. Depending on what else is going on on your system, you might have just hit the swap file / swap partition by allocating that much RAM at a chunk.

If there are other subtleties going on, I'm not aware of them, but memory usage is my first suspicion for why this is so slow.

Comment: You're probably underestimating the total amount of memory that's eventually allocated for this. But I really don't think that's the problem: 1GB isn't going to force you to swap on any modern system; and even so, we should only need to keep at most 10^6 elements in memory at any given time. GHC's allocator will eat a million allocations for breakfast; wait until you see how many gigabytes of allocation/deallocation appear in the profiling output of even simple, short-running programs.

Comment: No doubt; I'm not a Haskell expert (I know more about F#, and even there I'm only dabbling yet). @CYC, if anything Daniel Wagner says contradicts me, listen to him, not me. I'm mostly guessing.

Comment: @DanielWagner Why would it only need to keep 10^6 elements in memory at any given time?

Comment: @immibis it doesn't need to keep that many, but it might collect that many at once since the GC isn't going to execute after every element is consumed.